# Implement Dispose to my method

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a Winform application that uses Pcapdot.Net DLLs and plays Pcap files.
When I am playing a file in a loop I can see that the application memory is raised until a crash occurs and in stack trace I can see that this happens in the method that plays the file.
So I was thinking to add dispose method and see if it can solve this crash.

So I added to my class a variable `private bool _disposed;`

and methods:

```
public void Dispose()
{
    Dispose(true);
}

private virtual void Dispose(bool disposing)
{
    if (!_disposed)
    {
        if (disposing)
        {

        }

        _disposed = true;
    }
}
```

**my play method:**

```
public bool sendBuffer(PacketDevice packetDevice)
        {
            int count = 0;
            bool bContinuePlay = true;
            PacketDevice selectedOutputDevice = packetDevice;
            _shouldContinue = true;
            _isStop = true;
            _stopButton = true;

            OfflinePacketDevice selectedInputDevice = new OfflinePacketDevice(_filePath.FullName); //open the capture file
            DateTime time = DateTime.Now;
            double totalTime = 0;
            double totalDelayTime = 0;
            double deletaTime = 0;

            using (inputCommunicator = selectedInputDevice.Open(65536, PacketDeviceOpenAttributes.Promiscuous, 1000))
            {
                using (OutputCommunicator = selectedOutputDevice.Open(100, PacketDeviceOpenAttributes.Promiscuous, 1000))
                {
                    ThreadStart tStarter = delegate { openAdapterForStatistics(selectedOutputDevice); };
                    Thread thread = new Thread(tStarter);
                    thread.IsBackground = true;
                    thread.Start();

                    DateTime lastTime = DateTime.MinValue;
                    double delayTime = 0;
                    Packet packet;
                    IEnumerable<Packet> packets;

                    while (inputCommunicator.ReceivePacket(out packet) == PacketCommunicatorReceiveResult.Ok && _isStop) //fill the buffer with the packets from the file
                    {
                        if (count < _numberOfPacketsInfile)
                        {
                            using (PacketSendBuffer mSendBuffer = new PacketSendBuffer((uint)packet.Length * 4))
                            {
                                if (_isBurst)
                                {
                                    if (lastTime != DateTime.MinValue)
                                    {
                                        if (packet != null)
                                        {
                                            delayTime = (packet.Timestamp.Subtract(lastTime).TotalMilliseconds) / _playSpeed; //delay between packets
                                        }

                                        if (delayTime > 1000)
                                        {
                                            if (_startTimer != null)
                                            {
                                                _startTimer(delayTime, EventArgs.Empty);
                                            }

                                            _delayForNextPacket = delayTime;
                                        }

                                        totalDelayTime += delayTime;
                                        delayTime = delayTime - deletaTime;

                                        if (delayTime < 0)
                                        {
                                            delayTime = 0;
                                        }

                                        if (evePacketProgress != null)
                                        {
                                            int packetProgressPrecentage = (int)(((double)_numberOfSendPackets / _numberOfPacketsInfile) * 100);
                                            evePacketProgress(packetProgressPrecentage);
                                        }

                                        _mrEvent.WaitOne((int)delayTime);

                                        if (_stopTimer != null)
                                        {
                                            _stopTimer(delayTime, EventArgs.Empty);
                                        }
                                    } //end if
                                } // end if _brust                                                                                           

                                if (_fragmentation)
                                {
                                    foreach (Packet item in splitPacket(packet, 1))
                                    {
                                        mSendBuffer.Enqueue(item);
                                    }
                                }
                                else if (packet != null)
                                {
                                    lastTime = packet.Timestamp;
                                    mSendBuffer.Enqueue(packet);
                                }

                                if (evePacketProgress != null)
                                {
                                    int packetProgressPrecentage = (int)(((double)_numberOfSendPackets / _numberOfPacketsInfile) * 100);
                                    evePacketProgress(packetProgressPrecentage);
                                }

                                try
                                {
                                    OutputCommunicator.Transmit(mSendBuffer, _isBurst); //send the packet
                                    _numberOfSendPackets++;
                                }
                                catch (Exception)
                                {

                                }
                            }///

                            totalTime = DateTime.Now.Subtract(time).TotalMilliseconds;
                            deletaTime = totalTime - totalDelayTime;
                            count++;
                        }
                    } //end while
                }
            }

            return bContinuePlay;
        }
```

the crash occur in the line `DateTime lastTime = DateTime.MinValue;`

I am a new developer and do not know how to proceed from here.
Any help is welcome

Comment: Probably need to see that play code, guess that there's where the error is

Comment: Can you perhaps show how you are creating the file and using it in the loop..perhaps you should or could wrap the instance of the new file in a `using(){}` statement which will handle the disposing for you hard to recommend something without seeing the current code you are using

Comment: The problem probably comes from the fact that you play the file in loop without closing it, so the file stays in memory and the multiple copies reach memory limit. Can you post your loop?

Comment: @Brad M - surely its only missing the suppressFinalize if there actually is a finalizer, which isn't metntioned or shown?

Comment: see my update, also i call this function from BackgroundWorker

Comment: This dispose method isn't actually disposing the resources, either - you'll need to make it do *something* useful in terms of releasing those resources...

Comment: @NDJ I reckon the point is there should be a finaliser to cope for the use case where the object isn't explicitly disposed, and it needs to clean up unmanaged resources.

Comment: @NDJ An implementation of `IDisposable.Dispose` should always call `GC.SuppressFinalize(this)`, even if the class does not have a user-defined finalizer.

Comment: @RowlandShaw If you find yourself creating a finalizer in C#, you probably did something wrong - most of the time it indicates code that should be using a class derived from `SafeHandle`.

Answer (score 2):

The Dispose method is used to free unmanaged resources, in other words, what isn't in ".NET World", like a TCP or database connection.

When CLR finds that your program is running out of memory, it automaticaly invokes Garbage Collector, that free the objects you are not using anymore.

You only need to implement IDisposable if you have to free unmanaged resources. For details implementing IDisposable, you can find a lot of articles online. For instace, you are forgeting of implement your class finalizer.

So, if the problem is in the method that play the files, you must first find what is causing the memory to increase and cannot be released by GC.

I don't know Pcapdot.Net, but try to find a method for releasing the file being played, or something like this. Maybe you don't need to implement IDisposable, just add the call for this method.

Comment: That's not entirely true. You should implement dispose on objects that also consume other objects that implement IDisposable even if your object doesn't directly manipulate non-.NET resources. It is also useful for controlling the lifetime of memory hungry .NET objects by ensuring references to them are deterministically dropped, allowing the garbage collector to collect them.

Comment: Careful - it's true that Dispose is generally used to clean up unmanaged resources, but also to "deterministically release" managed resources, like unwinding event handlers, shutting down services, releasing locks, etc

Comment: -1: Several problems here. 1) You may need to implement `IDisposable` if your class contains fields that are `IDisposable`, even if your class does not directly own unmanaged resources. 2) If you find yourself writing a finalizer in C#, you probably did something wrong. This is not *always* the case, but your instinct should be to seriously question why it was added and look for a way to remove it (e.g. by using `SafeHandle` instead).

Comment: True, I forget these cases trying to simplify the answer, but the finalizer must be implemented to enforce the call to Dispose if the programmer forgot this. This [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms244737%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) ilustrates this.

Comment: the crash occur in the line `DateTime lastTime = DateTime.MinValue;`